# Ansible: loop our shell command(Linux user group search) result and display the groups

Tags: ansible

Ansible: loop our shell command(Linux user group search) result and display the groups

Task to check if group exist

```
- name: "Checking if group doesn't exist"
  shell: "grep -i {{ item.group }} /etc/group"
  register: presence
  loop: "{{ UserAddList.add_users }}"
  ignore_errors: true
  no_log: true
```

Json input file:

UserAddList is a json file

```
{
  "add_users": [
    {
      "name": "test1_123",
      "group": "test1_123",
      "additional_groups":
      [
        "test2",
        "group1"
      ],
      "password" : "test1_newcdsaf",
      "sudo_entry": "ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL",
      "comment": "test1"
    }
  ],
  "delete_users": [
                  ]
}
```

---

Task to display the groups doesn't exist

```
- name: The following groups does't' exist
  debug:
    msg:
      "{{ item._ansible_item_label.group }}"
  loop: "{{ presence.results }}"
```

output:

```
(item={
  '_ansible_parsed': True,
  'stderr_lines': [

  ],
  u'changed': True,
  u'stdout': u'',
  '_ansible_item_result': True,
  u'msg': u'non-zero return code',
  u'delta': u'0:00:00.008175',
  'stdout_lines': [

  ],
  '_ansible_item_label': {
    u'comment': u'test1',
    u'password': u'test1_newcdsaf',
    u'group': u'test1_123',
    u'name': u'test1_123',
    u'sudo_entry': u'ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL',
    u'additional_groups': [
      u'test2',
      u'group1'
    ]
  },
  u'end': u'2019-12-10 14:23:15.725676',
  '_ansible_no_log': True,
  'item': {
    u'comment': u'test1',
    u'password': u'test1_newcdsaf',
    u'group': u'test1_123',
    u'name': u'test1_123',
    u'sudo_entry': u'ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL',
    u'additional_groups': [
      u'test2',
      u'group1'
    ]
  },
  u'cmd': u'grep -i test1_123 /etc/group',
  u'failed': True,
  u'stderr': u'',
  u'rc': 1,
  u'invocation': {
    u'module_args': {
      u'warn': True,
      u'executable': None,
      u'_uses_shell': True,
      u'_raw_params': u'grep -i test1_123 /etc/group',
      u'removes': None,
      u'argv': None,
      u'creates': None,
      u'chdir': None,
      u'stdin': None
    }
  },
  u'start': u'2019-12-10 14:23:15.717501'
})=>{
  "changed": false,
  "item": {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "grep -i test1_123 /etc/group",
    "delta": "0:00:00.008175",
    "end": "2019-12-10 14:23:15.725676",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
      "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "grep -i test1_123 /etc/group",
        "_uses_shell": true,
        "argv": null,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "executable": null,
        "removes": null,
        "stdin": null,
        "warn": true
      }
    },
    "item": {
      "additional_groups": [
        "test2",
        "group1"
      ],
      "comment": "test1",
      "group": "test1_123",
      "name": "test1_123",
      "password": "test1_newcdsaf",
      "sudo_entry": "ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL"
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2019-12-10 14:23:15.717501",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [

    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": [

    ]
  },
  "msg": "test1_123"
}
```

I don't want to display the whole output, I just want to display the groups information.

The debug is printing all the input data as well.

Please any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

> The debug is printing all the input data as well.

It's actually not the `debug:` task that is printing your data, ansible is showing you what it is looping over. However, you are using `loop:` over the top-level `presence.results` list, and `.results` contains not only the output you care about, but also the invocation parameters, success or failure, and the actual returned data that you care about

There are two ways of fixing that problem: tell ansible that you only want it to show something smaller in the loop label, or change the `loop:` to actually only loop over the deleted users

In the first way, [`loop_control:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label) will do that (it even cites your exact circumstance in the docs saying *When looping over complex data structures, the console output of your task can be enormous. To limit the displayed output, use the label directive with loop_control*):

```
- name: The following groups does't' exist
  debug:
    msg:
      "{{ item._ansible_item_label.group }}"
  loop: "{{ presence.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item.name }}"
```

In the second way, just select out the group you care about and `msg:` it:

```
- name: The following groups does't' exist
  debug:
    msg:
      "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ presence.results | map(attribute='item') | map(attribute='group') | list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, That really helps

Comment: @Daniel I'm trying to fail the job if the group doesn't exist
`- name: Fail if any group doesn't exist in system from json file
  fail:
    msg:
      "{{ item }} One of the group doesn't exist"
  loop: "{{ verify_group.results | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}" ` 

 as stdout is empty I'm not able to print the group in the output.
 
 `TASK [verify_group : Fail if any additional groups doesn't exist in system from json file] 
failed: [135.104.174.73] (item=) => {"changed": false, "item": "", "msg": " One of the group doesn't exist"}
skipping: [135.104.174.73] => (item=group1)